# JMeter. Why doesn't if statement work?

Tags: jmeter

I am frustrated by my failure to get a simple IF statement to trigger and am begining to suspsect that I do not understand the way IF statements are implemented in JMeter.

What I am trying to do is query an API that returns 202 responses while it is processes a request, then returns a 200 when the results are returned. Finally a 404 is returned if I query again after getting the results.

I have a while controller with no condition that performs this query and it exits on the 404.

This seems to work OK.

What I want to do is confirm that I have valid JSON returned for the 202 and the 200 but ignore the 404.

I thought I could add an IF controller after each query in the loop to run a a BSF assertion when I have 202 or 200 but I cannot seem to get it to work. Even if I put in "true" or "1 == 1" as the condition the assertion is never called.

```
"${httpCode}" == "200"
```

In my assertion I have added a deliberate error "eval x;" that causes the assertion to fail if I drag and drop it to other parts of the suite -

```
try {
   eval('var response = ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString());
   eval x;
} catch(e) {
      prev.setSuccessful(false);
      prev.setResponseMessage("Invalid response. Expected a valid JSON.");
}
```

Like I said, even if I add true or 1 == 1 the assertion error never shows in the assertion results. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the way the IF controller works? Certainly the Java programmers I work with cannot see what is wrong here.

Unfortunately this site won't let me post an image of the suite...

BTW

Sorry for asking a "vague" question but I have been evaluating JMeter for over a week now and find the online resources to be lacking in "How To" type tutorials. Lots of references to specific JMeter objects and basic "Getting Started" type posts but nothing detailed. Also most of the references seem to be circular and and out of date; I keep finding myself back at the same pages over again.

The apache site seems more geared up as an object reference.

Is anyone able to recommend a really good online resource?

Comment: why dont you try Beanshell pre-post processors?

Answer (score 0):

What JMeter version do you have? In my ver.2.10 if controller with 1==1 works correctly.

Also I could recommend you to use If controller with  [JMeterThread.last_sample_ok function](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie). It returns true in case previous sampler was ok. 
You could use in as if condition.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I wanted to test the response code and take different actions for each possible response. I ended up implementing it in Beanshell which is probably a far more versatile approach anyway. My version is 2.11. Thanks again. Brad

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

${__BeanShell("${httpCode}".equals("200"))}